# Rspec Strong Parameter stripping out params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, strong-parameters

I'm failing a not-null condition in model creation, thanks, I think, to strong parameters removing things from my params hash.

Rspec code:

```
it "creates a new Provider" do
    expect {
      post :create, {:admin_provider => {:name => "foo bar"}}, valid_session
    }.to change(Provider, :count).by(1)
end
```

Controller Code:

```
def create
  @admin_provider = Provider.new(okay_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    ...Render Views
  end
end

def okay_params
  params.permit(:admin_provider).permit(:name)
end
```

Output:

```
Admin::ProvidersController POST create with valid params creates a new Provider
 Failure/Error: post :create, {:admin_provider => {:name => "foo bar"}}, valid_session
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint
   DETAIL:  Failing row contains (225, null, null, null, t, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null).
   : INSERT INTO "providers" DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING "id"
```

**What happened to my params to strip out the "name" parameter?**  I've tried it as a symbol and a string.  I've tried it as a let block instead of hardcoding.  No difference.  Every time it seems to be stripping out my params.  What am I missing?

Comment: `params.require(:admin_provider).permit(:name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `okay_params` definition as:

```
# app/controllers/providers_controller.rb

def okay_params
  params.require(:admin_provider).permit(:name)
end
```

Then your spec:

```
it "creates a new Provider" do
    expect {
      post :create, {:admin_provider => {:name => "foo bar"}}, valid_session
    }.to change(Provider, :count).by(1)
end
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit why params.require is behaving differently than params.permit?

Comment: @ABMagil, they are two different functions.  Please see: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html